# How to group by month in presto SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, presto

I am trying to group by per month in Presto SQL.
I tried this:

```
select
    date_trunc('month', CAST(date AS date)) date_month,
    sum(gross_revenue,0) AS 'monthly_net_revenue'
    from gross_revenue_calculator
    group by date_trunc('month', date)
```

This gives me the following error:
`Malformed query: line 61:27: mismatched input ''monthly_net_revenue''. Expecting: <identifier>`

Expected output:

```
October:  $102.12
November: $90.12
```

Comment: Remove quote chars: `AS monthly_net_revenue`. And use `GROUP BY date_month`.

Comment: Didn't work:  Now says: `FAILED: Presto error: COLUMN_NOT_FOUND: line 19:10: Column 'date_month' cannot be resolved`

Comment: This is presto error/issue - SQL syntax allows to refer to output column in GROUP BY... if this is not possible in presto then use an expression in GROUP BY which literally matches the output expression (remove CAST - it is obviously excess). Anycase the first part of my previous comment is a root of the error which you have posted in the question - fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use single quotes as column name it either no quotes or double, also you can reference columns by index in `GROUP BY` as you do in your `WITH` clause:

```
select
    date_trunc('month', CAST(date AS date)) date_month,
    sum(gross_revenue,0) AS monthly_net_revenue
from gross_revenue_calculator
group by 1
```